# Angular 2.0 left to right module and shadow DOM

Tags: angular, shadow-dom

I have a website which supports "right to left" language such as Arabic.
In case the language is arabic, I put on the body tag the `dir="rtl"` attribute. In this manner, all the inline positioned children are aligned from the right side, even if they are within custom components.

Now I would like to have a custom style in case or one of those components is inheriting a right to left directive. The common way to achieve so is as follow:

```
body[dir="rtl"] myComponent {
// custom style if I am in right to left
}
```

The problem is, using shadow DOM, the selector will not get the parent's attribute and therefore my style will not be applied. I am therefore wondering if there is any way a module to explicitly inherit from a parent property using Angular 2.0 ? In this way I could simply write

```
myComponent[dir="rtl"]{
// my stlyles
}
```

And I am done…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 Possible ways:

A. Best solution

```
:host-context([dir="rtl"]) myComponent{
// custom style if I am in right to left
}
```

B. Not working everywhere (yet?) relying on the [:dir pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:dir)

C. Programmatically explicitly put the class to the component (bad)

```
import {ElementRef, AfterContentInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
...
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @HostBinding('attr.dir')
  public dir:string;

  constructor(private element:ElementRef) {

  }

  public ngAfterContentInit():void {
    this.dir = getComputedStyle(this.element.nativeElement).direction;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no shadow DOM in Angular2 unless you set `ViewEncapsulation.Native`. Did you do that? There shouldn't be a problem with styles in Angular2. You can use `>>>` or `/deep/` to cross component borders.

If you add HTML dynamically (by some non-Angular JS lib) then `>>>` and `/deep/` can also be used but this would require to seem more code that demonstrates how your situation looks like exactly.